# git pull not working in Groovy

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins

I'm new to the Groovy language and am using it to write a custom parameter for a Jenkins job. In the script below, the first ("git checkout master") and last ("git branch -r --no-merged master") commands work just fine. However, the git pull doesn't execute as there is no output other than the initial '[git pull]' that I've commented below. What is returned from the last command, "git branch -r --no-merged master" is not correct because my origin is ahead of my local.

```
def dir = "C:/JenkinsBuilds/WidgetLoader/Source"
def srcDir = new File(dir)

String command1 = "git checkout master"
println ("[$command1]")
Process process1 = command1.execute(null, srcDir)
process1.waitFor()
println(process1.text)

String command2 = "git pull origin master"
println ("[$command2]") // This will output
Process process2 = command2.execute(null, srcDir) 
process2.waitFor()
println(process2.text) // Only a blank line is outputted

String command3 = "git branch -r --no-merged master"
println ("[$command3]")
Process process3 = command3.execute(null, srcDir)
process3.waitFor()
println(process3.text)

def branches = ["-- SELECT BRANCH --","master"]

process3.text.eachLine {line -> branches.add(line.trim().replaceAll('origin/', ''))}

return branches
```

This is what gets returned

[(master)]:
[git checkout master]
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 10 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

[git pull]

[git branch -r --no-merged master]
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/testb1
  origin/testb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out what was going on thanks to a snippet of code I found [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/groovy/src/test/groovy/execute/ExecuteTest.groovy.shtml).

```
def command2 = "git pull"
println ("[$command2]")
StringBuffer sbout = new StringBuffer()
StringBuffer sberr = new StringBuffer()
Process process2 = command2.execute(null, srcDir) 
process2.waitForProcessOutput sbout, sberr
def value = process2.exitValue()
int count = sbout.toString().readLines().size()
println "${sberr.toString()}"
println "Exit value: $value, Err lines: ${sberr.toString().readLines().size()}, Out lines: $count"
assert count > 1
assert value == 0
```

> [git pull] Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository.

My issue was that there were no exceptions being thrown on the git pull and it is not very clear on how to see if there are any other errors. That being said, I thought I'd share this code snippet in case someone else runs across a similar issue.

This permissions error I can work with and has nothing to do with my original question so I'm marking this comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Command arguments should **always** be passed as `List`. Try:

```
def command1 = ["git", "checkout", "master"]
def command2 = ["git", "pull", "origin", "master"]
def command3 = ["git", "branch", "-r", "--no-merged", "master"]
```

Comment: The first one and third commands work just fine without putting them into a list. It's the pull that does not seem to work. Regardless, I've tried this both with and without using a list and the pull still does not work.

Comment: Opal - If command arguments should always be passed as List could you please explain these examples that are not using a list: http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management, http://www.joergm.com/2010/09/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy/, http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-executing-string-or.html,

Comment: Yes, these examples are quite easy. It seems that you haven't been doing much of executing external commands via groovy. The fact that an instance of `String` can be *executed* does not mean this is the correct and not error prone way of doing it.